# "no rule to make target" for target created by another makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

The main makefile is this, as you can see it calls to two other makefiles in the subdirs: `comm` and `bc`.

I know that I don't use makefile shortcuts like treating all `cpp` files at once but please don't pay attention to that right now.

In `comm/makefile` there is a rule to make `comm/build/Communication.o` but somehow I don't know how to tell that fact to the main makefile.

```
CPPFLAGS=-g -c --std=c++11 -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/boost -Ibc/inc -Icomm/inc
LDFLAGS=-g -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lQt5Core -lboost_system -lpthread  -lboost_thread 

all: comm/bin/party bc/bin/bctest bin/protocol

comm/bin/party:
    cd comm && $(MAKE)

bc/bin/bctest:
    cd bc && $(MAKE)

bin/protocol:build/main.o \
             build/TrustedParty.o \
             build/Player.o \
             build/utils.o \
             comm/build/Communication.o \
             comm/build/FileParser.o \
             comm/build/Party.o \
             comm/build/PeerConnection.o \
             comm/build/ServerModule.o \
             comm/build/Utilities.o \
             bc/build/BooleanCircuit.o \
             bc/build/Gate.o \
             bc/build/Wire.o
    g++ -Wall $^ -o bin/protocol $(LDFLAGS)


build/main.o:src/main.cpp
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC  src/main.cpp -o build/main.o

build/TrustedParty.o:src/TrustedParty.cpp
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) src/TrustedParty.cpp -o build/TrustedParty.o  

build/Player.o:src/Player.cpp
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) src/Player.cpp -o build/Player.o

build/utils.o:src/utils.cpp
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) src/utils.cpp -o build/utils.o

clean:
    rm -fr build/* bin/*
    rm -fr comm/build/* bin/*
    rm -fr bc/build/* bin/*
```

When I run `make` it returns

```
16:15:03 **** Build of configuration Default for project bmr ****
make all 
g++ -g -c --std=c++11 -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/boost -Ibc/inc -Icomm/inc -fPIC  src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++ -g -c --std=c++11 -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/boost -Ibc/inc -Icomm/inc src/TrustedParty.cpp -o build/TrustedParty.o  
g++ -g -c --std=c++11 -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/boost -Ibc/inc -Icomm/inc src/Player.cpp -o build/Player.o
g++ -g -c --std=c++11 -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/boost -Ibc/inc -Icomm/inc src/utils.cpp -o build/utils.o
make: *** No rule to make target `comm/build/Communication.o', needed by `bin/protocol'.  Stop.

16:15:11 Build Finished (took 7s.821ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `comm/Makefile` knows how to build that target correctly (`make build/Communication.o` in the `comm` directory works); then if you really want to get this to work correctly (and you might not want to, see [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) for why) you need to tell the toplevel make what to do in this situation.

Something like this:

```
comm/build/%.o:
    @$(MAKE) -C comm $(patsubst comm/%,%,$@)
```

Comment: any suggestion on how to make it the correct way in the first place? (without adding patches..)

Comment: The solution to this problem that doesn't involve that sort of fix is to stop using recursive make and start using a non-recursive make system. I haven't read it (yet) but the author knows his stuff so [this](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/painless-non-recursive-make) might be of some help here but the general idea is that you only have one make process for the entire build.